# Create Array of Current Year and Last Year Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create an Array of Years. Current year and Last Year. The following code is working however I wanted to see if there is a cleaner way of doing this?

```
var d = new Date();
    var currentYear = (d.getFullYear());
    var lastYear = (d.getFullYear() - 1);

    $scope.years = [
        currentYear,
        lastYear
    ];
```

Comment: Looks pretty clean to me.

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to JS and programming in general and wanted to see if it could be improved.

Comment: The *only* thing I might change is instead of `var lastYear = (d.getFullYear() - 1);` I'd probably use `var lastYear = currentYear - 1;`.

Comment: Thank you I like the look of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   var d = new Date();
   var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
   var lastYear = currentYear - 1;
   $scope.years = [currentYear,lastYear];
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid duplicating

```
var d = new Date();
var currentYear = (d.getFullYear());
var lastYear = (currentYear - 1); //Remove another call to d.getFullYear()

$scope.years = [
    currentYear,
    lastYear
];
```

If you are not using the variable currentYear later, you could even reduce it to:

```
var d = new Date();
var currentYear = (d.getFullYear());

$scope.years = [
    currentYear,
    currentYear - 1
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get current year like this

on your *.ts* file:

```
public getYear() {
    return new Date().getUTCFullYear();
  }
```

and then you can use on your html file like this

```
{{getYear()}}
```